# Find the conditional CDF of the sum of exponential r.v given X = x

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $\text{Expo}(λ)$, and $T = X + Y$ .
>
> (a) Find the conditional CDF of $T$ given $X = x$.
>
> (b) Find the conditional PDF $f_{X\mid T}(x\mid t)$, and verify that it is a valid PDF.

Can you help me to verify that the PDF is valid?

I found the following PDF

$P(T \le t\mid  X=x)=P(Y \le t-x)=1-e^{-λ(t-x)}\implies$

$f(T \le t \mid X=x)=λe^{-λ(t-x)}$, to verify that it is valid:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} λe^{-λ(t-x)}$ and I compute that the integral is divergent!

Comment: Consider: What is the support for $Y+x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is not divergent. \begin{align*}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}f_{T|X}(t|x)\text{d}t=\int_{x}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-x)}\text{d}t=\left.-e^{-\lambda(t-x)}\right\vert_{x}^{\infty}=1\end{align*}

The reason is that $t\ge x$.